# How do I remove the on screen keyboard from the logon screen in Windows Remote Desktop Server 2008 R2?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server

The on screen keyboard (OSK) from the "ease of access" tools pops up on EVERY connect to the server, even if you have not activated it.

I can't seem to find a control panel or reg setting to switch it off.

It is VERY "in your face" for linux users who connect at lower resolutions and do not provide all credentials, but have to type username and password.

I'm running a 2008 R2 Terminal Server/Remote Desktop Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to:

Start > Control Panel > Ease of Access Center > Use the computer without a mouse or keyboard > Uncheck 'Use On-Screen Keyboard'

Comment: I believe that was what I ended up doing, but I think it somehow "didn't take" the first time(s) I did it, and so I thought there had to be something else.

Answer (score -1):

If about do not seem to work try this :

click "change administrativ settings" to the left on the "Ease of Access Center"

Check “Apply all settings to the logon desktop” -->Apply

This work for me !

Comment: you're not adding new content...

Answer (score -1):

if you can click to setting button on OSK
you will see a link at bottom of the setting screen
with this link you can permamently close osk in login screen